# How do I use Rcpp code in a stand-alone C++ program?

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am a Statistician who works a lot with scientists in other fields who are not using R but mostly C++. On occasion I would like to give them a C++ program they can run but that also uses R functionality. Here is a toy example

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int mytry() {
  NumericVector x(5);
  x = rnorm(5);
  Rcout<<mean(x)<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Now when I try to run this in a C++ compiler (I am using Code::Block) I am getting error messages such as

undefined reference to 'Rprintf'

and a list of other similar errors.

I apologize if this is a silly question but I am not an C++ expert. I only use it myself via Rcpp to replace small R code snippets with C++ so they run faster.

Comment: Two close votes in 20 mins?  Wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you cannot as `Rcpp` is designed and built as an R extension package that can *always* assume to be called from R and hence link with many R symbols.  In fact, it requires it.

You have two basic options here: the first and more common one is to separate your C++ implementations into 'pure C++' you can hand to your colleagues, along with some remaining 'glue' to call from R / return to R. That is likely your best option---just think, *e.g.*, in terms of `std::vector<double>` rather than `Rcpp::NumericVector`. We have ample documentation for working with STL types such as `std::vector`.

The second is to actually stick R into your C++ application for which you can use CRAN package [RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside) which also makes heavy use of `Rcpp`.  Both approaches have examples here (you can search among 3000 `Rcpp` answers by adding `[rcpp]` to the search term) and at places like the [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/).
And of course for all of this, and more, you can always take a look at the [Rcpp Introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) which covers this.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I will see what approach works better for me.

Comment: The rcpp-devel list is a friendly (and in these days of online forums quiet) place where you can ask.  Lots of people will have simpel examples, and I do show the very use case of splitting R/C++ hybrids into 'pure C++ bits' and 'glue' in some of my slide decks for Rcpp workshops.

Comment: I deliberately wrote my question in a simplified way. The "real" question is this. I am an associate member of CMS, one of the large collaborations of physicists at the LHC. Physicists (and Astronomers) have for the longest time done their own thing when it comes to Statistics, and have written their own software to do it. Finally over the last 20 years or so they have begun to talk to Statisticians about their analyses. Now understandably they are not just going to switch to R and give up on their own software.

Comment: So the real question is what to do if they want to use something that is already implemented in some R package. If some sizable part of the package is also written in C++, I was hoping that they could port that at least.

Comment: Again, bigger/longer discussions belong on the mailing list or maybe the repo---not a Slackoverflow comment.  ROOT reached out to us when Rcpp was younger but we never managed to meet. But let me assure you that _many_ people have done _many_ different things with R and Rcpp (and RInside) and you do not need to reinvent any wheels.  You can also work with R headles etc. :It all depends" so lets have a deeper discussion elsewhere.